# setInterval functionality in javascript using functions

Tags: javascript

how can i implement the javascript code for setInterval with using only javascript functions(i should not be using setInterval(function(){},1000)). and i should not be using any kind of libraries for making that possible.
    Can any one please help me with this???

Comment: It isn't directly possible to implement timing functions in JavaScript, that's why these timing functions exist. Why can't you just use the native timing functions? What other API's can you use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive setTimeout

```
var timerId = setTimeout(function run() {
  alert( "sec" );
  timerId = setTimeout(run, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: the setTimeout is also not working in this... i need to implement with only functions. i should not be using the setTimeout/setInterval etc., i have already tried to do so, but it haven't run. but even i will try again with your code, thanks for your response.

Comment: you can't create setTimeout or setInterval like function using functions in javascript. Those are inbuilt function that call a function asynchronously.